# How to calculate transformation from a camera to a motion capture's coordinate frame?

Tags: coordinate-systems

I have a motion capture system (optitrack) that can give me the pose of a rigid body tracked by the system. I have attached a camera to the rigid body in an arbitrary location and pose. Given any 3D point P in the camera's coordinate frame, I would like to calculate the point P' in the motion capture's coordinate frame. Would you please tell me what is the process for finding the transformation that relates the camera's coordinate frame to the motion capture's coordinate frame?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, it is called hand-eye calibration. There is more info here: http://campar.in.tum.de/Chair/HandEyeCalibration